# CSS grid: ensure dynamic rows are all of a specific size

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a bit of a strange situation. I am trying to use a CSS grid to put content side by side. The problem is that one side of the content is dynamic so should be automatic in height while the other side should be a fixed size.

Here's an example of what this looks like:

```css
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 16px);
  grid-auto-rows: fit-content(16px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.text {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: auto;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.description {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 5;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="text">
  Nam adipiscing. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Fusce egestas elit eget lorem.

Quisque rutrum. In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

Fusce pharetra convallis urna. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Donec mi odio, faucibus at, scelerisque quis, convallis in, nisi. Etiam sollicitudin, ipsum eu pulvinar rutrum, tellus ipsum laoreet sapien, quis venenatis ante odio sit amet eros.

Fusce pharetra convallis urna. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Donec mi odio, faucibus at, scelerisque quis, convallis in, nisi. Etiam sollicitudin, ipsum eu pulvinar rutrum, tellus ipsum laoreet sapien, quis venenatis ante odio sit amet eros.
</div>
<div class="description">
   <img src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/y/c/r/G/g/M/warning-md.png" alt='Warning clip art' style="height: 100%;" />
</div>
</div>
```

So the idea here is: I want my content to be 4 columns of 25% width each and 5 rows of a fixed height (16px each). This is the blue area in the snippet. However because the text content can vary (red area) I would like the content to be able to take up more rows if necessary, however I don't want the expansion to affect the image (green area).

I have tried using auto rows but that has the side-effect of stretching the image as well because the row height is automatic. I am not sure if this is even possible using only grid.

Comment: why 5 rows of 16px instead of one row of 80px and the remaining auto?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok so the long story is that this is coming from a content editing tool that basically shows a grid to users with 80 rows and 4 columns (I similified here to 5x4). The text initially is placed within this grid with fixed height but when viewing there is currently a feature request to make the height dynamic to not show scrollbars in the text. This is why the rows in this view are fixed to a specific width and height. It's basically because this is how it was so far. I guess I could ditch the entire fixed row thing for fixed heights as you suggest, it seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the height of the image and don't define any row configuration:

```css
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.text {
  grid-column: span 3;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.description {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="text">
  Nam adipiscing. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Fusce egestas elit eget lorem.

Quisque rutrum. In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

Fusce pharetra convallis urna. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Donec mi odio, faucibus at, scelerisque quis, convallis in, nisi. Etiam sollicitudin, ipsum eu pulvinar rutrum, tellus ipsum laoreet sapien, quis venenatis ante odio sit amet eros.

Fusce pharetra convallis urna. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Donec mi odio, faucibus at, scelerisque quis, convallis in, nisi. Etiam sollicitudin, ipsum eu pulvinar rutrum, tellus ipsum laoreet sapien, quis venenatis ante odio sit amet eros.
</div>
<div class="description">
   <img src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/y/c/r/G/g/M/warning-md.png" alt='Warning clip art' style="height: 100%;" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please help me here with right approach, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75410495/15916627