# Position:absolute issue in react native

Tags: android, css, ios, react-native, tablet

I am making a react native application in which there is a left and right section.

The left section consists of `flex:0.7` and right side section consists of `flex:0.2`.

Inside the left section I have a container inside which there is a [`ImageBackground`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground) which looks like a circuit skeleton

[image]

and inside that I am in the need to place sub components in the respective position.

**Expected Result:**

[image]

**Things I have tried:**

Pure HTML and CSS way: *(Working as expected)*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.leftSection {
  flex: 0.7;
}

.rightSection {
  flex: 0.2;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.bgContainer {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.coil {
  position: absolute;
  top: 49.55%;
  left: 24.3%;
  width: 17.4418605%;
}

.evaporator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.25%;
  left: 54.5%;
  width: 11.627907%;
}

.compressor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 53.15%;
  left: 59.2%;
  width: 13.0813953%;
}

.component img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftSection">
    <div class="bgContainer">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png" class="bg-img" />
      <div class="component coil">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
      </div>
      <div class="component evaporator">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
      </div>
      <div class="component compressor">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightSection">
    Right Section
  </div>
</div>
```

But as I am doing this in a react native application, I have tried changing this into a **react native** way like,

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet, Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  leftSection: {
    flex: 0.7,
  },
  rightSection: {
    flex: 0.2,
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
  },
  bgContainer: {
    position: 'relative',
    margin: 0,
  },
  bgImg: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  coil: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '49.55%',
    left: '24.3%',
    width: '17.4418605%',
  },
  evaporator: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '7.25%',
    left: '54.5%',
    width: '11.627907%',
  },
  compressor: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '53.15%',
    left: '59.2%',
    width: '13.0813953%',
  },
  componentImg: {
    width: '100%',
  },
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.leftSection}>
        <View style={styles.bgContainer}>
          <ImageBackground
            source={{ uri: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png' }}
            style={styles.bgImg}
          >
          <View style={styles.coil}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png' }}
              style={styles.componentImg}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.evaporator}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png' }}
              style={styles.componentImg}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.compressor}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png' }}
              style={styles.componentImg}
            />
          </View>
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.rightSection}>
        <Text>Right Section</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Issue:**

After the implementation,

The below screenshot is captured in the screen viewport with *height: 844* and *width: 1280*

[image]

The below screenshot is captured in the screen viewport with *height: 552* and *width: 1024*

[image]

I am making this mainly for tablet screens of all height and width but in pure HTML and CSS way, this is responsive but in tablet screen's in react native, its not responsive at all.

Kindly please help me to solve this issue of making the `position:absolute` elements responsive and located at same position across all the screen's without distortion.

*Note:* Edited my question to mention that this implementation is happening in react-native.

Comment: Try to prepare a grid, mybe can be a better solution in this case

Comment: as you are using background size cover, you would need to make sure the other images resized with the background too. You could then use relative units to absolutely position the image to where you want.  But you need to make an attempt at it first

Comment: @Pete, Thanks for your comment. I have tried something like `.coil {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 55%;
}` but it is not the right way and hence seeking for help. Kindly apologize me for not that and please provide a right solution to achieve the expected result.

Comment: I think you might need to set min-width or min-height on the container, and on this note overflow: auto as well, because the absolute divs that are within your container will not resize with screen resolutions, because the position absolute removes them from the element flow, meaning that they will not be effected and stretched by anything.

Comment: @Sfili_81, I have edited this question now. Please take a look on the same. Thanks.

Comment: Your background image is centered and contained. You'll need a centered wrapper div with same size as your background image to work as a positional reference for the additional image elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.container {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png');
    height: 400px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 700px;
}
.coil {
    position: absolute;
    top: 204px;
    left: 180px;
    zoom: 101%;    }
.evaporator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 320px;
    zoom: 121%;
}
.compressor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    left: 422px;
    zoom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an option. But, keep in mind, this is a construction with hard-coded coordinates. When you change the size of the container with the background image, you will also need to change the positions of the nested elements.

```html
<style>
  .container {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png");
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .container div {
    border: 2px solid orange;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .coil {
    top: 256px;
    left: 36px;
  }
  
  .evaporator {
    top: 40px;
    left: 296px;
  }
  
  .compressor {
    top: 272px;
    left: 333px;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so?

```html
<style>
  .container {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png");
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* position: relative; */
  }
  
  .container div {
    border: 2px solid orange;
    /* position: absolute; */
  }
  
  .coil {
    margin-top: 111px;
    margin-left: 33px;
  }
  
  .evaporator {
    margin-top: -343px;
    margin-left: 140px;
  }
  
  .compressor {
    margin-top: 170px;
    margin-left: -49px;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution on flexbox instead of making it position:absolute as requested.

```css
.container {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png');
    height: 400px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 700px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.coil, .evaporator, .compressor {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.evaporator {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: 140px
}

.coil {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-right: 231px;
}

.compressor {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 88px;
    margin-left: 218px;
    margin-top: -90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's bitmap image, I would suggest to go back to the real size of each element, and to position them regarding their real size. All that in pixels. If really needs resizing outer container, more or less same can be done taking percentage of each element regarding the big one and their position left top same kind of calculation...

```css
.container {}

.circuit {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circuit>img {
  /* 688 x 401 */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 688px;
  height: 401px;
}

.coil {
  /* 120 x 90 */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 120px;
  height: 90px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 199px;
}

.evaporator {
  /* 80 x 70 */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 375px;
  top: 25px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 70px;
}

.compressor {
  /* 90 x 120 */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 405px;
  top: 213px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circuit">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png" alt="circuit" />
    <div class="evaporator">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
    </div>
    <div class="coil">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
    </div>
    <div class="compressor">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way.

```
.container {
background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png');
height: 400px;
background-position: center;
background-size: contain;
width: 700px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
.coil {
position: absolute;
top: 204px;
left: 180px;
zoom: 100%;    }
.evaporator {
position: absolute;
top: 26px;
left: 320px;
zoom: 115%;
}
.compressor {
position: absolute;
top: 220px;
left: 422px;
zoom: 100%;
}



<div class="container">
 <div class="coil">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
 </div>
 <div class="evaporator">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
 </div>
 <div class="compressor">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
 </div>
</div>;
```